# Why my Odoo Qweb report is different in production and in test?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I'm on Odoo 10, I've got a production environment and a test environment.

When I copied a report from test to production, it is different : the font is bigger (but it's the same file !).

Is there a setting which modify the qweb report ?

Comment: Is that real data you're showing here? You should think about deleting it and to share "demo" or "dummy" data instead. To your question: do both documents have the same font? Does the paperformat in both Odoos have the same DPI? Are you sure both Systems are exactly the same?

Comment: Yeah i will delete these datas.
It is the same font but not he same height.
How to know the paperformat and DPI in odoo ?
My boss tell me it's te copy of the production's VM

Comment: Hm okay, than it's weird. The paperformats can be found in the Technical menu (activate developer mode and switch to Settings menu)

Comment: For paperformats it's exactly the same thing. I found my report in Technical > Report  and no differences neither.

Comment: @CZoellner no other ideas ?

Comment: My boss tell me no needs to continue, but if someone has a solution i like to have it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a `wkhtmltopdf` issue.

If you:

1) have the same qweb

2) have the same paperformat

3) and generaly speaking have everything that touches this report the same

Then your last call is to do `wkhtmltopdf --version` on both instances to verify the version, and then make sure that they run the same.

Comment: I think about it yesterday and I have checked, but they are both at version 0.12.4

Comment: Also, do not forget to check that the report is generated and not fetched from the database: Open your Report and uncheck the `Reload From Attachment`.